# オリジナルのアレイリストの作り方

Tags: java

アレイリストをどうやって作ればいいですか？

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 Direction<String> list = new Earray<String>();
list.add("11");
list.add("345");
list.add("56");
list.add("52");
 
System.out.println("List are: " + list);
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.addAll();
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.remove("11");
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.contains();
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.updateAll();
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.isEmpty();
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
list.clear();
System.out.println(" List are" + list); 
System.out.println(list.size());
 
//tests for adding a null value
    }
 
}

public interface Direction<E> extends Iterable<E> {
  boolean add(E toAdd);
  boolean addAll(Collection<E> values);
  void clear();
  boolean contains(E e);
  boolean isEmpty(); 
  void updateAll(E oldValue, E newValue);
  boolean remove(E e) ;
  int size() ;
}
public class Earray<E> implements Direction<E>{
I want to make something like this(example of Earray
E[]Earray
int size
add(E toAdd)
E[size]=toAdd
size++)
 
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() 
{
return null;
}
 
@Override
public boolean add(E toAdd) {
return false;
}
 
@Override
public boolean addAll(Collection<E> values) {
//addAll() requires an instance of java.util.Collection. So I need to make a java.util.Collection, put items in there, and then pass it to arrayList variable.
return false;
}
 
@Override
public void clear() {
}
 
@Override
public boolean contains(E e) {
return false;
}
 
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
return false;
}
 
@Override
public void updateAll(E oldValue, E newValue) {
 
}
 
@Override
public boolean remove(E e) {
return false;
}
 
@Override
public int size() {
return 0;
}
 
//but cannot use something like List<T> mylist = new ArrayList<T>(); 
}
```

Comment: 「実現したいこと」に対して、現状のコードではどのような問題があるのかも説明した方がアドバイスも付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 質問内容が解決したのであれば、あとから来た同じ問題を抱えた人たちのために自己回答をしてください。質問のほうはロールバックしておきました。